# Is "Her coming home was unprecedented" correct?

Tags: grammar

Her coming home was unprecedented?

Do all verbs have gerunds like "coming" in the sentence above?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Formally _her_ is possessive, and the corresponding form with _he_ would be _his coming home_. But many people today don't use the possessive in this construction, and would say _him coming home_. Of course, with "her", there is no difference.

Comment: @ColinFine Many will argue that "him" is used rather than "his" because the standard of English is not what it once was. GCSE does not begin to compare with the old GCE O Level. At least that is what my former colleague who reads the Daily Telegraph thinks.

Comment: Either one can be used, and both have been used for centuries. Gerunds just can't have nominative subjects, that's all. Though there are verbs (notably modal auxiliary verbs) that don't have gerunds -- there is no gerund verb form *_musting_ or *_coulding_ from _must_ or _could_, for instance. The really interesting thing about the _-ing_ suffix is that it's totally regular when it occurs: it's always infinitive + _-ing_, no exceptions, not even for _be_ (regular form _being_).

Comment: @JohnLawler: Might this somewhat quirky book title be the ***only*** "semi-acceptable" exception in the entire lexicon? [***Doing and Don'ting** - A Workbook in Moral Identity.*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Title-Doing-Donting-Workbookin-Identity/dp/078720062X)

Comment: Words can always be quoted and reified, and when that happens you start over and apply normal regularities. Like _English cooking_ but not *_New English cooking_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. "Coming home" is a gerund phrase, which acts as a noun, and it belongs to "her". It is a somewhat uncommon or old-fashioned construction though, at least where I am from.

You could do this with pretty much any verb. "His running away was unexpected", "Its running aground was inevitable" etc.